# getaddrinfo, AI_PASSIVE - different behaviour windows <-> linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, sockets

I have adapted the code from http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html (selectserver.c -- a cheezy multiperson chat server) to compile on Windows. The complete code follows below. I compile using gcc version 6.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project). I compile using gcc6.1.0 on Linux, too.

Basically, you run it, telnet 2 or more times to port 9034, and whatever you type in one telnet session gets echoed to the other telnet sessions (depending on the system, one has to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> before it gets echoed - on Windows it echoes every character typed).

Now the problem :

On Linux AMD64 or ARM, I can connect to it from localhost and from another system, be that Windoes or Linux.  On Windows, it only works on localhost, and I fail to understand why. The fact that `hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;` is specified makes it listen on all interfaces, if I understand things correctly.

The [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> Setting the AI_PASSIVE flag indicates the caller intends to use the returned socket address structure in a call to the bind function.
>
> When the AI_PASSIVE flag is set and pNodeName is a NULL pointer, the IP address portion of the socket address structure is set to INADDR_ANY for IPv4 addresses and IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT for IPv6 addresses.

The code reads :

```
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &ai)) != 0)
```

How do I make this behave correctly on Windows?

It is compiled with :

> g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\chatserver.o" "..\src\chatserver.cpp"

and linked with

> g++ -mwindows -o chatserver.exe "src\chatserver.o" -lws2_32

What do I need to change in the code please?

This is the complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef __linux__
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#endif

#define PORT "9034" // port we're listening on
// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) { return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr); }
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}
int main(void)
{
    #ifdef _WIN32
        WSADATA wsaData;                                                        // Initialize Winsock
        int nResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
        if (NO_ERROR != nResult) {
             printf ("Error occurred while executing WSAStartup().");
        }
    #endif

    fd_set master; // master file descriptor list
    fd_set read_fds; // temp file descriptor list for select()
    int fdmax; // maximum file descriptor number
    int listener; // listening socket descriptor
    int newfd; // newly accept()ed socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;
    char buf[256]; // buffer for client data
    int nbytes;

    char remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int yes=1; // for setsockopt() SO_REUSEADDR, below
    int i, j, rv;
    struct addrinfo hints, *ai, *p;
    FD_ZERO(&master); // clear the master and temp sets
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    // get us a socket and bind it
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &ai)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        exit(1);
    }
    for(p = ai; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        listener = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (listener < 0) { continue; }
        // lose the pesky "address already in use" error message
        setsockopt(listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *)&yes, sizeof(int));
        //setsockopt(listener, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, "1", sizeof(int));
        if (bind(listener, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        close(listener);
        continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    // if we got here, it means we didn't get bound
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: failed to bind\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(ai); // all done with this
    // listen
    if (listen(listener, 10) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(3);
    }
    // add the listener to the master set
    FD_SET(listener, &master);
    // keep track of the biggest file descriptor
    fdmax = listener; // so far, it's this one
    // main loop
    for(;;) {
    read_fds = master; // copy it
    if (select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("select");
    exit(4);
    }
    // run through the existing connections looking for data to read
    for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) { // we got one!!
        if (i == listener) {
            // handle new connections
            addrlen = sizeof remoteaddr;
            newfd = accept(listener,
            (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr,
            &addrlen);
            if (newfd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            }
            else {
                FD_SET(newfd, &master); // add to master set
                if (newfd > fdmax) { // keep track of the max
                    fdmax = newfd;
                }
                std::cout << "selectserver: new connection on socket " << newfd;
                /*
                printf("selectserver: new connection from %s on "
                "socket %d\n",
                inet_ntop(remoteaddr.ss_family,get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr),remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN),newfd);
                */
            }
        }
        else {
            // handle data from a client
            if ((nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0)) <= 0) {
                // got error or connection closed by client
                if (nbytes == 0) {
                    // connection closed
                    std::cout << "selectserver: socket " << i << " hung up";
                }
                else {
                    perror("recv");
                }
                close(i); // bye!
                FD_CLR(i, &master); // remove from master set
            }
            else {
            // we got some data from a client
            for(j = 0; j <= fdmax; j++) {
                // send to everyone!
                if (FD_ISSET(j, &master)) {
                    // except the listener and ourselves
                    if (j != listener && j != i) {
                    if (send(j, buf, nbytes, 0) == -1) {
                        perror("send");
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        } // END handle data from client
        } // END got new incoming connection
        } // END looping through file descriptors
    } // END for(;;)--and you thought it would never end!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to open the port on the firewall?

Comment: I did yes. disabled everything in firewall.cpl too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getaddrinfo()` can return multiple IP addresses.  You are correctly looping through all of the returned addresses, but you are breaking the loop after the first successful `bind()`, and then you are calling `listen()` on that one single socket, regardless of its socket family.  Since you are using `AF_UNSPEC` when calling `getaddrinfo()`, it is possible that it is returning *BOTH* `INADDR_ANY` for IPv4 *AND* `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT` for IPv6.

Change your code to listen on every IP address that `getaddrinfo()` returns, and to keep track of those sockets so you can use all of them in your `select()` loop.  If you just wanted to listen on either `INADDR_ANY` or `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT`, there would be no point in using `getaddrinfo()` at all, as you could just hard-code the `socket()`/`bind()` calls for those two addresses and get rid of the loop altogether.  The purpose of using `getaddrinfo()` in this manner is to let it decide what you should be listening on, given the `AI_PASSIVE` hint you provided.  Don't make assumptions about its output.

You also cannot use `fdmax` on Windows, so you need to re-write your `select()` loop.  Sockets on Windows do not use file descriptors, so you can't simply loop from `0 <= fdmax` when calling `FD_ISSET()`, and the first parameter of `select()` is ignored as well.  I suggest not storing your active socket descriptors/handles in a master `fd_set` to begin with.  Use a `std::list` or other suitable container instead, and then dynamically create a new `fd_set` whenever you need to call `select()`.  This would be more portable across different platforms.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#ifdef __linux__
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define SOCKET int
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1

inline int closesocket(int s) { return close(s); }
inline int getLastSocketError() { return errno; }
#endif

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

inline int getLastSocketError() { return WSAGetLastError(); }
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm> 
#include <utility> 

#define PORT "9034" // port we're listening on

#ifdef _WIN32
#define SELECT_MAXFD 0
#else
#define SELECT_MAXFD fdmax+1
#endif

enum eSocketType { stListener, stClient };

struct SocketInfo
{
    SOCKET sckt;
    eSocketType type;
};

SocketInfo makeSocketInfo(SOCKET sckt, eSocketType type) {
    SocketInfo info;
    info.sckt = sckt;
    info.type = type;
    return info;
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void* get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    std::list<SocketInfo> master; // socket descriptors
    std::list<SocketInfo>::iterator i, j;
    SOCKET sckt, newsckt; // socket descriptors

    fd_set read_fds; // temp file descriptor list for select()
    #ifndef _WIN32
    int fdmax; // maximum file descriptor number
    #endif

    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;
    char buf[256]; // buffer for client data
    int nbytes;

    char ipAddr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int yes = 1; // for setsockopt() SO_REUSEADDR, below
    int rv;
    struct addrinfo hints, *ai, *p;

    #ifdef _WIN32
    WSADATA wsaData; // Initialize Winsock
    rv = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (NO_ERROR != rv) {
        std::cerr << "WSA startup failed, error: " << rv << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    #endif

    // get us the listening sockets and bind them

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &ai);
    if (rv != 0) {
        std::cerr << "selectserver: getaddrinfo failed, error: " << gai_strerror(rv) << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    for(p = ai; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        sckt = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (INVALID_SOCKET == sckt) {
            std::cerr << "selectserver: socket failed, error: " << getLastSocketError() << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        // lose the pesky "address already in use" error message
        setsockopt(sckt, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *)&yes, sizeof(int));
        //setsockopt(sckt, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, "1", sizeof(int));
        if (bind(sckt, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
            std::cerr << "selectserver: bind failed, error: " << getLastSocketError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(sckt);
            continue;
        }

        // listen
        if (listen(sckt, 10) < 0) {
            std::cerr << "selectserver: listen failed, error: " << getLastSocketError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(sckt);
            continue;
        }

        /*
        std::cout << "selectserver: listening on IP " << inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr(p->ai_addr), ipAddr, sizeof(ipAddr)) << ", socket " << sckt << std::endl,
        */

        // add the listener to the master list
        master.push_back(makeSocketInfo(sckt, stListener));
    }

    freeaddrinfo(ai); // all done with this

    // if we got here, it means we didn't get bound
    if (master.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "selectserver: failed to bind" << std::endl;
        return 3;
    }

    // main loop
    while (1) {
        #ifndef _WIN32
        fdmax = 0;
        #endif

        FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
        for (i = master.begin(); i != master.end(); ++i) {
            sckt = i->sckt;
            FD_SET(sckt, &read_fds);
            #ifndef _WIN32
            fdmax = std::max(fdmax, sckt);
            #endif
        }

        if (select(SELECT_MAXFD, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            std::cerr << "select failed, error: " << getLastSocketError() << std::endl;
            return 4;
        }

        // run through the existing connections looking for data to read

        for(i = master.begin(); i != master.end(); ) {
            sckt = i->sckt;

            if (!FD_ISSET(sckt, &read_fds)) {
                ++i;
                continue;
            }

            // we got one!!
            if (stListener == i->type) {
                // handle a new connection
                addrlen = sizeof(remoteaddr);
                newsckt = accept(sckt, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);
                if (INVALID_SOCKET == newsckt) {
                    std::cerr << "accept failed on socket " << sckt << ", error: " << getLastSocketError() << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    master.push_back(makeSocketInfo(newsckt, stClient)); // add to master list

                    std::cout << "selectserver: new connection, socket " << newsckt << std::endl;
                    /*
                    std::cout << "selectserver: new connection from " << inet_ntop(remoteaddr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr), ipAddr, sizeof(ipAddr)) << ", socket " << newsckt << std::endl,
                    */
                }
            }
            else {
                // handle data from a client
                nbytes = recv(sckt, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
                if (nbytes <= 0) {
                    // got error or connection closed by client
                    if (nbytes == 0) {
                        // connection closed
                        std::cout << "selectserver: socket " << sckt << " disconnected" << std::endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cerr << "selectserver: recv failed on socket " << sckt << ", error: " << getLastSocketError() << std::endl;
                    }
                    closesocket(sckt); // bye!
                    i = master.erase(i); // remove from master list
                    continue;
                }

                // send to everyone!
                // except a listener and ourselves

                for(j = master.begin(); j != master.end(); ) {
                    if ((j->sckt != sckt) && (stClient == j->type)) {
                        if (send(j->sckt, buf, nbytes, 0) < 0) {
                            std::cerr << "selectserver: send failed on socket " << j->sckt << ", error: " << getLastSocketError() << std::endl;
                            closesocket(j->sckt); // bye!
                            j = master.erase(j); // remove from master list
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    ++j;
                }
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }

    for(i = master.begin(); i != master.end(); ++i) {
        closesocket(i->sckt);
    }

    #ifdef _WIN32
    WSACleanup();
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

If you are running the code on a system that supports dual-stack sockets (like Windows), you can change `AF_UNSPEC` to `AF_INET6` (or just hard-code `socket()`/`bind()` without using `getaddrinfo()`) to create only IPv6 listener(s) on `IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT`, and then disable the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option on them.  This will allow IPv6 listen sockets to accept both IPv4 and IPv6 clients, reducing the number of listen sockets you need to create.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer - it works - I'll try to absorb and extend it within a few days :) . There are 3 small typo's in the listing - a ; after the struct a , after the 0 where the select call has been split up between windows and else and an std::cerr with a missing :  I can't correct that. With these fixed it compiles on my systems. Haven't tried linux yet.